# Git diff shows changes that aren't in a commit

Tags: git, merge, git-diff, git-log, git-show

Something happened to our dev branch such that a lot of code from the release branch got merged into it. I'm trying to track down where these changes occurred but I get some very puzzling results. When I run `git diff HEAD@{2}` it shows a list of changes including many files that haven't been touched in months, implying that `HEAD@{2}` is the commit that brought in the bad code as I see it. However if I run `git show HEAD@{2}` it shows a rather innocuous  commit that only touches two files. Further, when I run `git reset --hard HEAD@{2}` it seems to fix the issues and to top off all the weirdness after I tried that reset twice and then undid it with `git reset --hard origin/dev` it now appears that the commit with all the extra code is at `HEAD@{1}`.

I can't seem to make head or tails of this so any suggestions/pointers/tips or tricks would be welcome but some directed questions that are puzzling me are: how can this code have gotten into the branch if there wasn't a merge commit? If someone cherry-picked a commit from a production branch to the dev branch could that be related to this? What are the differences (if any) in how `git show` and `git diff` resolve commits?

The current theory I have given limited git knowledge: it seems that these changes weren't part of any commit but somehow got into the tree right around `HEAD@{2}` so `diff` shows the changes as it walks the object tree but `show` doesnt see them as they're not part of a commit. Does this make any sense or am I way off base?

Either way, thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Every time you move the place to which `HEAD` points, including using `git reset`, the relative numbers change.  If you were looking at something and then did `git reset --hard HEAD@{2}` you created a new log entry for HEAD so now you have to use `HEAD@{3}` to refer to the same underlying commit-ID.  Just as a point of note, then, I find using raw IDs, or setting a temporary tag, tends to work better for this stuff...

Comment: Interesting, more investigation makes me realize that I now see that changeset in `HEAD@{1}..HEAD@{2}` and `HEAD@{3}..HEAD@{4}` so I guess resetting to `origin/dev` pushed the original one back and added a new one at the top?

Comment: Essentially, yes: every time you update a reference name (branch name or `HEAD`, mostly, but "remote branches" have logs as well), git logs the previous name/SHA-1 pair in the "reflog" for that reference (stored in in `.git/logs/`).  The `@{...}` syntax tells git to look in the reflog, and a numeric value is "how many to step back from the latest".  You can also use `@{yesterday}`, `@{1 hour ago}`, and various other forms, although many require quoting to prevent the shell from mangling them.  Use `git reflog` or `git reflog branchname` to view the ref-log for `HEAD` or a specific branch.